# A sad violin song in most of flashback scenes like Obito's flashback and the storybook from Jiraiya

Tags: naruto, music

There's a violin track in *Naruto Shippuden* that's kind of sad or emotional. It starts with a little guitar or banjo, then continued with a violin.

Up until season 18, most of the time the song comes up in a flashback, like Obito's flashback, and in the storybook from Jiraiya, and even more of them. One example is in episode 440 in the book from Jiraiya, the song starts at 17:17. Another example is from episode 464, around minute 17.

I have checked all the OST, but I couldn't find it.

What is the name of the song?

Answer (score 1):

This was not released in any of the official OSTs. At the very least, it doesn't appear in any of the tracks in [this list](https://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Music#Original_Soundtracks) (as of 2018).

There are some unofficial versions online, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R451rerZ_Fw), titled "Minato saves Kushina".

I remember this song as that nostalgic-sounding track that is mostly happy, but has just a touch of bittersweetness, and also that really good violin bit.

Not to be confused with ["Let Me Tell You a Story from My Childhood"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dajWMHH-JDk), which sounds similar and also has some very nice violin parts, but unlike the first song, is more lighthearted and cheerful.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is *Loneliness* , you can search it up in Youtube as *Naruto Shippuden OST - Loneliness.*

Also check out *Sadness and Sorrow* , as both have guitar, banjo and violin.

Comment: Still not that :( it’s really that track that comes up on the episode I specified I mean it comes in couple but not gonna search out all of them haha but thanks every body anyway and let’s hope someone out there know the answer 

Answer (score -1):

I think it's a song called "Senya". You can find it [here](https://youtu.be/440UkXOXL0E).

Answer (score -2):

One that I had trouble finding was [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uK8SX-6wAgs). I hope it is the one you were looking for. It seems to fit your description, though I couldn't verify the episode timestamps.

[Here is a playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3EFB5805B9DDB6BA) with several other unreleased tracks (though some may have been released since).